# Router stacking component in SPA website

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

Im learn to make a Single Page Application using ReactJS and  I follow this tutorial https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic .
[react router basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZwJ.png)
Im success to implement that tutorial, but now im very confusing about component in react router. Im trying to make a login page with a login form or a welcome page maybe. Im confuse about component like navbar or sidebar on the render component, it always displayed in every component or page. How to make it dissapear ?

Sorry my english

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following code in the `BasicExample` component:

```
<ul>
  <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
</ul>
```

`BasicExample` is a layout component so all the other components (i.e `Home`, `About`, `Topics` and `Topic`) are included in it.

`BasicExample` should look like this afterwards:

```
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

**PS:** I'm a bit curious as to why you don't want navigation in an app that has routes. Maybe you shouldn't be using React Router at all.

Comment: but the page is blank without it. I just know using react router to navigate between page

Comment: It shouldn't be. Except you removed the `Route` tags. Showing me a snippet of your code would give me more insight.

Comment: Thanks! I have an idea. Thanks for your solution :)